# Excel AVERAGE function

Tags: excel, function, average

I generating random number by =RANDBETWEEN(1300;1500)/100 and for that function I using this function to generate value 1-5:

```
=IF(C5<13,4;"1";IF(C5<=13,79;"2";IF(C5<=14,19;"3";IF(C5<=14,59;"4";IF(C5>14,6;"5")))))
```

so I got in line 10 number 1-5 and I need count average from that but if i do =AVERAGE(C5:C14)
it just say ######.

[image]

Comment: try expanding the column width

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess that by `=AVERAGE(C5:C14)` you mean `=AVERAGE(E5:E14)` whose values are text, since applied within double inverted commas, so your average formula is naturally giving an error.

Try removing the double inverted commas in your long formula.